# SQL looking for duplicates in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table I'm working with looks like this

| id_psg | town_from | town_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rostov | Moscow |
| 1 | Rostov | Paris |
| 2 | Rostov | Moscow |
| 2 | Singapore | London |
| 2 | Singapore | London |
| 3 | London | Singapore |
| 3 | London | Singapore |
| 4 | Singapore | London |
| 4 | London | Singapore |
| 4 | Singapore | London |
| 5 | London | Singapore |
| 5 | London | Singapore |
| 5 | Paris | London |

We have data of people differentiated by their passanger IDs, from which town to which they travelled.

At first I was looking to find passenger IDs who have travelled from only 1 location to only 1 destination (no matter how many times they did that). So I grouped the table by id_psg and looked for duplicates. This code achieved that goal.

```
SELECT id_psg
FROM passengers
GROUP BY id_psg
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT town_from) = 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT town_to) = 1
```

The result I got was

```
|id_psg|
|------|  
|3     |
```

Now I'm trying to get a result of passenger IDs of passengers who have travelled only between 2 towns, not necessarily one way, but also possibly back and forth. The result would have to look like this.

```
|id_psg|
|------|  
|3     |  
|4     |
```

Because passenger with the ID 4 has travelled only from Singapore to London or from London to Singapore.
This task requires me to search for duplicates between 2 columns instead of 1 and that's what I can't solve.

Comment: Union the same dataset with swapped `to` and `from` and count distinct contatenations of `to` and `from`. It should be equal to 2.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? [Edit] the question and add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select id_psg
from ((select id_psg, town_from as town
       from passengers
      ) union all
      (select id_psg, town_to as town
       from passengers
      )
     ) p
group by id_psg
having count(distinct town) = 2;
```

Note that this easily generalizes to more towns.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b2385a12d8d6b6d8859988e31e3f2d1f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```sql
SELECT id_psg
FROM passengers
GROUP BY id_psg
HAVING (
        MIN(town_from) = MIN(town_to) AND
        MAX(town_from) = MAX(town_to) AND
        COUNT(DISTINCT town_from) = 2 AND
        COUNT(DISTINCT town_to) = 2 )
    OR (
        COUNT(DISTINCT town_from) = 1 AND
        COUNT(DISTINCT town_to) = 1
    );
```

The MIN/MAX assertions ensure that the same pair of towns appears in both `town_from` and `town_to`.  The distinct count assertions ensure that the passenger travelled in both directions at least one time.  Or, your current criteria for one way travel can be used.

Comment: . . This would not return id = 3.

Comment: The language of the question made it unclear whether the OP wanted both one way and two way, or just the latter.